# Creating a pokemon type game in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

Does any know of any tutorials or topics on this? Idk what a pokemon type game is called. I guess what I'm really interested in is how to lay out the terrain and buildings and making sure the character does not walk through buildings basically how to create the "map" and how to bind the character to a path on that map. I know how to do most of the other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/roleplaying_game

Answer (score 1):

It's a 2D tile based game, so search for material using that phrase.

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=2d+tile+based+game+tutorial

This looks like a decent tutorial:
http://upfgeeks.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/tuto-tile-engine.pdf